# How do I add a custom field to a eloquent model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to add custom fielt to eloquent model on load. Method with appends do not work when process result collection

```
protected $appends = ['formatted_date'];
public function getFormattedDateAttribute()
{
    return $this->date->format('D-m-y');
}
```

When I try then $collection->pluck($key, 'formatted_date'), I got error ** Unknown column 'formatted_date' in 'field list'**

Comment: Solved, problem was with source data to collection, if use $collection = Table::whereBetween('date',[$from, $to]) , just needed add get() to it

Answer (score 0):

Did You try this?

```
 $collection->toArray();
 $collection->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this cause error

```
$collection = Table::whereBetween(‌​'date',[$from, $to]);
$result = $collection->pluck($key, 'formatted_date');
```

This works correct:

```
$collection = Table::whereBetween(‌​'date',[$from, $to])->get();
$result = $collection->pluck($key, 'formatted_date');
```